# Forecasting sales per item in Azure ML algorithm choice

Tags: machine-learning, prediction, forecasting

I have almost 10 years of sales data, let's assume in below format:

```
 DateKey    Product     Count    Price      Type 

 20140701    Shoe        10      $100         X
 20140701    Shoe         5      $40          Y
 20140702    Shirt       50      $80          Z
 20140703    Shoe        10      $105         A
.

.

 20180630   . ......
```

Now I want to predict this financial Year (2018-19) sales breakdown.

I have sales data for July 2018 which I can use to score my model, But I am not sure which algorithm to use. I am using Azure ML Studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of sample experiments in Cortana Gallery. This [one](https://gallery.azure.ai/Experiment/Time-Series-Forecasting-8) for example may provide you a brief overview of time series forecasting using Azure ML Studio

Comment: I gave up working on that data set, I aggregated the sales figures per day and just want to forecast daily sales in the next year. Do I have to use time series with R in this case?

Comment: Well, for me nothing changes as you have only changed the periodicity, with the prediction horizon of 365 days, right? Just have a look on this (https://a-little-book-of-r-for-time-series.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/timeseries.html). The logic is pretty simple: you first detect the global pattern, adjust your prediction model and set the horizon.